# div Overlay for every div in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, overlays

I'm trying to make a simple list that shows me a div overlay for every div in the array, but I am having problems defining each div.

My current java/jQuery script involves creating a div for each object in the array along with a background image (which I am also have trouble with links. I got an online link working for the background image though.).

What I want to do is provide an overlay for every item in the list and then in the future use the same code to provide the ability to open a link or show an image preview, but that's for another list.

So, how can I get the overlay working for each div rather than acting by class. I was able to create a div with all my desired settings for each object array, along with the overlay.

You will find in my document ready function the code that currently hides/shows every overlay div.

I want to define this to individual divs' in the array rather than all.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  displayDesign();
  $( ".pagesListOverlay" ).mouseenter(function() {
    $( ".pagesListOverlay" ).hide()  ;
  });
});
var arrayVariableDesign = [
  {name: "object1", type:"type1", company:"company1", dateYear:"2017", dateMonth:"08", dateDay:"24", image:"../images/preview/noimg.png"},
  {name: "object2", type:"type1", company:"company1", dateYear:"2017", dateMonth:"01", dateDay:"20", image:"../images/preview/noimg.png"},
  {name: "object3", type:"type2", company:"company2", dateYear:"2016", dateMonth:"08", dateDay:"24", image:"../images/preview/noimg.png"},
  {name: "object4", type:"type3", company:"company3", dateYear:"2016", dateMonth:"03", dateDay:"04", image:"../images/preview/noimg.png"},
  {name: "object5", type:"type1", company:"company2", dateYear:"2017", dateMonth:"02", dateDay:"24", image:"../images/preview/noimg.png"},
  {name: "object6", type:"type2", company:"company1", dateYear:"2017", dateMonth:"08", dateDay:"20", image:"../images/preview/noimg.png"},
];
var arrayLength_Design = arrayVariableDesign.length;
var temp_Design;
    
function displayDesign() {
    
  for (i = 0; i < arrayLength_Design; i++) { 
    var sortDate_Design = arrayVariableDesign[i].dateYear + arrayVariableDesign[i].dateMonth + arrayVariableDesign[i].dateDay;
    temp_Design = document.createElement('div');
    temp_Design.className = 'pagesListBtn mobilePagesListBtn';
    temp_Design.style.background = "url(" + arrayVariableDesign[i].image.src + ")"; // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790347/set-an-image-object-as-a-div-background-image-using-javascript
    temp_Design.style.backgroundSize = "100%";
    temp_Design.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
    temp_Design.style.backgroundPosition = "50% 50%";
    temp_Design.style.backgroundColor = "#C02024";
    temp_Design.innerHTML = "<div class='pagesListOverlay mobilePagesListOverlayBtn'>" + arrayVariableDesign[i].name + " for " + arrayVariableDesign[i].company + "<br>" + arrayVariableDesign[i].type + "<br>" + arrayVariableDesign[i].dateDay + "/" + arrayVariableDesign[i].dateMonth + "/" + arrayVariableDesign[i].dateYear + "</div>";
    document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(temp_Design);
  }
}
```

```css
.pagesListBtn {
  z-index: 500;
  background-color: #C02024;  
  display: inline-block;         
}

.pagesListBtn:hover {
  background-color: #920400;    
}

.pagesListOverlay {
  padding-top: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: inherit;
  background-color: white; 
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight:900;
  line-height:30px;
}

.mobilePagesListBtn {
  min-height:150px;
  max-height:150px;
  width: 100%; /*295px*/
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
}

.mobilePagesListOverlayBtn {
  min-height:150px;
  max-height:150px;
  width: 100%; /*295px*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

I am also experiencing two other problems with this code.

1. The image links are not working, I just copied and pasted from my css file
2. I get a lot of 'missing strict statements everywhere' - I fixed this by adding "use strict"; to my code.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So you wish to hide the overlay on mouse enter... But for this div entered, not all... Right on this? And do you want the overlay to be displayed back on mouse leave ?

Comment: Yes, other way around mate. I just did that to test the display of the overlay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` on the parent `.pagesListBtn`. From `$(this)`, wich is the `.pagesListBtn` hovered, find the children `pagesListOverlay` to show/hide it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  displayDesign();
  $( ".pagesListBtn" ).mouseenter(function() {
    $( this ).find(".pagesListOverlay").fadeOut(800)  ;
  });
  $( ".pagesListBtn" ).mouseleave(function() {
    $( this ).find(".pagesListOverlay").fadeIn(800)  ;
  });
  
  
});
var arrayVariableDesign = [
  {name: "object1", type:"type1", company:"company1", dateYear:"2017", dateMonth:"08", dateDay:"24", image:"../images/preview/noimg.png"},
  {name: "object2", type:"type1", company:"company1", dateYear:"2017", dateMonth:"01", dateDay:"20", image:"../images/preview/noimg.png"},
  {name: "object3", type:"type2", company:"company2", dateYear:"2016", dateMonth:"08", dateDay:"24", image:"../images/preview/noimg.png"},
  {name: "object4", type:"type3", company:"company3", dateYear:"2016", dateMonth:"03", dateDay:"04", image:"../images/preview/noimg.png"},
  {name: "object5", type:"type1", company:"company2", dateYear:"2017", dateMonth:"02", dateDay:"24", image:"../images/preview/noimg.png"},
  {name: "object6", type:"type2", company:"company1", dateYear:"2017", dateMonth:"08", dateDay:"20", image:"../images/preview/noimg.png"},
];
var arrayLength_Design = arrayVariableDesign.length;
var temp_Design;
    
function displayDesign() {
    
  for (i = 0; i < arrayLength_Design; i++) { 
    var sortDate_Design = arrayVariableDesign[i].dateYear + arrayVariableDesign[i].dateMonth + arrayVariableDesign[i].dateDay;
    temp_Design = document.createElement('div');
    temp_Design.className = 'pagesListBtn mobilePagesListBtn';
    temp_Design.style.background = "url(" + arrayVariableDesign[i].image.src + ")"; // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790347/set-an-image-object-as-a-div-background-image-using-javascript
    temp_Design.style.backgroundSize = "100%";
    temp_Design.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
    temp_Design.style.backgroundPosition = "50% 50%";
    temp_Design.style.backgroundColor = "#C02024";
    temp_Design.innerHTML = "<div class='pagesListOverlay mobilePagesListOverlayBtn'>" + arrayVariableDesign[i].name + " for " + arrayVariableDesign[i].company + "<br>" + arrayVariableDesign[i].type + "<br>" + arrayVariableDesign[i].dateDay + "/" + arrayVariableDesign[i].dateMonth + "/" + arrayVariableDesign[i].dateYear + "</div>";
    document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(temp_Design);
  }
}
```

```css
.pagesListBtn {
  /*z-index: 500;*/
  background-color: #C02024;  
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  display:block;
}

.pagesListBtn:hover {
  background-color: #920400;    
}

.pagesListOverlay {
  padding: 0;   /* changed */
  margin: 0;    /* changed */
  height: 150px;    /* added */
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: inherit;
  background-color: white; 
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight:900;
  line-height:30px;
}

.mobilePagesListBtn {
  height: 150px;      /* added */
  /*min-height:150px; 
  max-height:150px;*/
  width: 100%; /*295px*/
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 25px;
  /*margin-bottom: -15px;*/
}

.mobilePagesListOverlayBtn {
  /*min-height:150px;
  max-height:150px;*/
  padding:0;    /* added */
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%; /*295px*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks, all right there in front of me. Why didn't I think of that.

Okay so, how can I animate this?

Also there is one little problem. The div moves when it hiden/shown.

Comment: It touched your CSS... The jumpy effect was due to `.pagesListBtn` `display:inline-block`. And I removed/changed a couple things. For the animation, I used a fadeIn/fadeOut... Which is quite nice ;)

Comment: Hey Louys, another error I am having an issue with this. Posted as an answer below.

Comment: Ok I see... But you should not post another question as an answer like this... Create another whole question please. ;) Delete that answer. I will find your other question easily.